# VBA ErrorHandler, msoFileDialogOpen Loops Forever

Tags: vba, excel, ms-office, excel-2010

My ErrorHandler and msoFileDialogOpen loop forever. Here is the code I want to fix:

```
Public Sub FunctionFileExplorer()
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding in the file)

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

    vFileName = CVar(strFilename)
    '   Display paths of each file selected
        For Count = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        Next Count
        For Each vFileName In .SelectedItems
            MsgBox strFilename
            FunctionFileExplorer
        Next
    End With

    ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number
    MsgBox "If you want to force the program to run, go to the line below and insert a ' mark to comment the line out." & vbNewLine & "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler", vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

    End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you calling the routine from within itself?

Comment: Do you want it to always access the ErrorHandler or did you forget an Exit Sub?

Comment: From what you've posted, the ErrorHandler will never be called because there's no "goto ErrorHandler" statement. Please post where that is in the code. Also, I agree with Roland that you always include an Exit Sub or a Resume after the MsgBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is a recursive function, i.e. it always calls itself, so it will always run unless you give it an exit point. See here where it calls itself:

> ```
>     For Each vFileName In .SelectedItems
>         MsgBox strFilename
>         FunctionFileExplorer
>     Next
> ```

If you want the user to be able to select multiple files and then you do something with those, this is the code:

I've deleted the code you didn't need and added the `Exit Sub` before the error handler.

```
Public Sub FunctionFileExplorer()
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data (simple GUI, much easier than coding in the file)

Dim vFilename As Variant

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Show

    '   Display paths of each file selected
        For Each vFilename In .SelectedItems
            MsgBox vFilename
            'FunctionFileExplorer ' comment out this line
        Next
    End With

CleanUp:
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error detected" & vbNewLine & "Error" & Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number
    MsgBox "If you want to force the program to run, go to the line below and insert a ' mark to comment the line out." & vbNewLine & "On Error GoTo ErrorHandler", vbCritical, "Error Handler: Error " & Err.Number

    End Sub
```